# Laravel 5.6 app : errors running npm install

Tags: laravel-5, npm-install

I need to run laravel application on my local

```
$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
4.15.0-23-generic
x86_64


$ nodejs --version 
v10.5.0


$ npm --version  
6.1.0


$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.6.26


$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 70 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.15): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.7.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v4.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.25.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.45): Loading from cache
  - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.2.0): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                    
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                               
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.6.26): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                               
  - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.0.0): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                   
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.0.2): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                 
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                     
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                            
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                            
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.6): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                        
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.7): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                   
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.7.1): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                 
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.0): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                            
  - Installing mockery/mockery (1.1.0): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                   
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.2.0): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                       
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v2.0.3): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                             
  - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1): Loading from cache                                                                                                                                                                                 
  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/diff (3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (3.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (6.0.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.7.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing phar-io/version (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (7.2.6): Loading from cache
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-intl (To show region name in time zone dump)
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock ()
egulias/email-validator suggests installing ext-intl (PHP Internationalization Libraries are required to use the SpoofChecking validation)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.6).)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers and the ping methods on schedules (~6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use the Flysystem cache (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Required to use the Flysystem SFTP driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing nexmo/client (Required to use the Nexmo transport (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/dom-crawler (Required to use most of the crawler integration testing tools (~4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to psr7 bridging features (~1.0).)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.6.0)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^2.0)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-soap (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

But I have errors running  npm install :

```
$ npm install
```

...
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back get-stream@3.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/got/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back file-type@5.2.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/file-type'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back p-map-series@1.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/p-map-series'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back pify@3.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/download/node_modules/pify'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back mimic-response@1.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/mimic-response'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back is-natural-number@4.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/is-natural-number'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back p-event@1.3.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/p-event'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back pify@2.3.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/pify'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back file-type@3.9.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress-unzip/node_modules/file-type'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back strip-dirs@2.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/strip-dirs'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back get-proxy@2.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/get-proxy'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back sort-keys-length@1.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/sort-keys-length'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back get-stream@2.3.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back url-to-options@1.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/url-to-options'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back tunnel-agent@0.6.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back ext-name@5.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/ext-name'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back decompress-targz@4.1.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress-targz'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back p-timeout@1.2.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/p-timeout'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back caw@2.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/caw'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back get-stream@3.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back duplexer3@0.1.4 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/duplexer3'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back decompress-tar@4.1.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress-tar'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back base64-js@0.0.8 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/base64-js'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back decompress@4.2.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back get-stream@3.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/execa/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back filenamify@2.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/filenamify'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back filename-reserved-regex@2.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/filename-reserved-regex'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back timed-out@4.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/timed-out'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back img-loader@2.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/img-loader'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back has-to-string-tag-x@1.4.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/has-to-string-tag-x'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back config-chain@1.1.11 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/config-chain'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back execa@0.7.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back npm-conf@1.1.3 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/npm-conf'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back proto-list@1.2.4 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/proto-list'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back is-object@1.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/is-object'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back unbzip2-stream@1.2.5 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/unbzip2-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back has-symbol-support-x@1.4.2 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/has-symbol-support-x'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back cross-spawn@6.0.5 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back buffer@3.6.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/buffer'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back laravel-mix@2.1.11 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/laravel-mix'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back execa@0.10.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back bin-build@3.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back pngquant-bin@4.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress-targz'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back download@6.2.5 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/download/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back decompress-tarbz2@4.1.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress-tarbz2/node_modules/file-type'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back got@7.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/got/node_modules/get-stream'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back decompress-unzip@4.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/decompress-unzip/node_modules/file-type'
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back imagemin-pngquant@5.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/cross-spawn'
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-06-26T03_35_30_550Z-debug.log
```

and I have file /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-06-26T03_35_30_550Z-debug.log(more 800 kb), so last lines with errors :

```
34849 silly saveTree │ └── yargs@8.0.2
34849 silly saveTree ├── lodash@4.17.10
34849 silly saveTree ├── popper.js@1.14.3
34849 silly saveTree └── vue@2.5.16
34850 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
34851 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
34852 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
34852 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
34852 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
34852 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
34853 verbose stack Error: pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
34853 verbose stack Exit status 1
34853 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
34853 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
34853 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
34853 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
34853 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
34853 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
34854 verbose pkgid pngquant-bin@4.0.0
34855 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/ukfxdev/new.exchangerates.org.uk
34856 verbose Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
34857 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
34858 verbose node v10.5.0
34859 verbose npm  v6.1.0
34860 error code ELIFECYCLE
34861 error errno 1
34862 error pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
34862 error Exit status 1
34863 error Failed at the pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall script.
34863 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
34864 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Why I have errors and how to fix them ?

Thanks!

Comment: I remember seeing this before but not how I fixed it. I believe I updated npm to fix it. what version are you using? `npm --version` to check. Some quick things to try are (1) `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`. (2) `rm package-lock.json && npm install` (kind of sucks but sometimes a conflicted package-lock messes things up

Comment: where are you trying to run npm install>

Comment: Try: 1. `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`; 2. `npm install -g pngquant-bin`; Then, try again. If the problem persists, do: `sudo rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`. It should work.

Comment: did you solve your problem?